# default entry field in tkinter with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm writing a small app using tkinter and Python to create a popup and ask for some input.

Currently I have to click on the text field before I can enter data. As there is only one text field I would like to just be able to type and the text field to be automatically active and ready to accept input, without having to first select the field.

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `textfield` is the Text object,
call `textfield.focus()` to make the text field automatically active.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
textfield = tk.Text(root)
textfield.pack()
textfield.focus()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm using an entry field rather than a text field but it all still works!